# The Power Of Negative Thinking: Yoneda Lemma for 0-categories, (-1)- categories and (-2)-categories?

Tags: category-theory

After reading through these talks by John Baez by https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608420.pdf , specifically "The Power Of Negative Thinking", where the $n$-categorical point of view is extended to $-1$ and $-2$ categories, I wondered: Is there a version of Yoneda's Lemma for $0$-categories, $(-1)$-categories or $(-2)$-categories?

I have trouble coming up with the formulation. This is a careful restatement of YL for $1$-categories (size issues aside):

**Preliminaries:**
If $C$ is a 1-category, for any two objects there is a $0$-category of morphisms.
More precisely a $1-$Functor: $$\mathrm{Hom} : C^{\mathrm{op}} \times C \rightarrow 0-\mathrm{Cat} $$
to the $1$-category of all $0$-categories $0-\mathrm{Cat}$.
(1)-PreSheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ are $1$-Functors to $0-\mathrm{Cat}$, which form a $1$-Category again. The $1$-Yoneda Embedding is the $1$-Functor
$$h:c \mapsto h_c=\mathrm{Hom}(-,c)$$
**Yoneda's Lemma for 1-categories:**
The function $$\mathrm{Hom}(h_c,X)\rightarrow X(c), \quad \theta \mapsto \theta_c(1_c) $$
is an isomorphism of presheaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yoneda for $0$-categories?

A $0$-category is a set $X$, a $0$-functor is a map of sets $f : X \to Y$, and a morphism $f \to g$ (natural transformation) between two $0$-functors exists, and is unique, if and only if $f=g$. A $0$-category is naturally enriched in the *discrete* monoidal category $\{0,1\}$ via*
$$\hom(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = y \\ 0 & x \neq y \end{cases}.$$
So when looking at representable functors, we should look at maps $f : X \to \{0,1\}$, which correspond to subsets $A \subseteq X$ via $A = \{x \in X : f(x)=1\}$. The representable functor $\hom(x,-)$ corresponds to the singleton $\{x\} \subseteq X$.

In the full Yoneda Lemma, we talk about morphisms $\hom(x,-) \to f$, which here exist, and are then unique, if and only if $f = \hom(x,-)$, i.e. $A = \{x\}$ for the subset $A \subseteq X$ corresponding to $f$. On the other hand, we have the value $f(x) \in \{0,1\}$, which is $1$ iff $x \in A$. So it seems like the Yoneda Lemma would say that $A = \{x\}$ iff $x \in A$, which is absurd.

*As of writing this, I noticed that this is actually wrong. We don't have a morphism $\hom(x,y) \times \hom(y,z) \to \hom(x,z)$ in $\{0,1\}$, namely when $x = z \neq y$! So it seems like the whole approach using enriched categories does not work, and it's not clear how to formulate Yoneda otherwise.

#### Enriched categories

The conceptual reason for this is that the discrete monoidal category $\{0,1\}$ is not well-behaved. Generally speaking, in enriched category theory we need a monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$ that is complete to even construct the enriched functor category, namely here we define
$$\hom(F,G) := \int^{x} \hom(F(x),G(x))$$
as an end in $\mathcal{V}$. (For details, see Kelly's classic book on enriched categories.)

But the discrete category $\{0,1\}$ does not even have a terminal object! This is the conceptual reason why functor categories are ill-behaved here.

#### Yoneda for preorders

To establish a $0$-dimensional Yoneda Lemma, we should instead take the poset $\{0< 1\}$ with the evident monoidal structure. It is complete so everything is fine. A category enriched in $\{0 < 1\}$ is then a $(0,1)$-category, or equivalently a preordered set. The correspondence is
$$\hom(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \leq y \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$
An enriched functor is the same as an order-preserving map, and a morphism $f \to g$ between two order preserving maps exists and is unique iff $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$.

If $X$ is a preorder, a functor (=order-preserving map) $f : X \to \{0 < 1\}$ can equivalently be described by an [upper set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) $A \subseteq X$. If $f,f' : X \to \{0,1\}$ are two functors, we have $f \to f'$ iff $A \subseteq A'$ for the corresponding upper sets.

Next, if $x \in X$, the representable functor $\hom(x,-) : X \to \{0 < 1\}$ corresponds to the upper set $X_{\geq x} := \{y \in X : x \leq y\}$.

Therefore, the Yoneda Lemma for $(0,1)$-categories states the following:

> If $A \subseteq X$ is an upper set, then $X_{\geq x} \subseteq A$ if and only if $x \in A$.

When you want to prove this (trivial) statement, the argument will be identical to the one for the $1$-dimensional Yoneda Lemma. In particular, the proof of $\implies$ uses the [universal element](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+element) $x \in X_{\geq x}$.

#### Yoneda for $0$-categories!

Every $0$-category (=set) is a $(0,1)$-category in particular. The partial order is just very trivial: $x \leq y$ iff $x = y$. Every subset is an upper set, and $X_{\geq x} = \{x\}$. Thus, the Yoneda Lemma for $0$-categories states:

> If $A \subseteq X$ and $x \in X$, then $\{x\} \subseteq A$ if and only if $x \in A$.

The usual corollaries hold: A subset is determined by the singletons it contains, and two singletons are equal iff they have the same element.

PS: I have also thought a bit about the Yoneda Lemma for $(-1)$-categories, of which there are exactly two ($\bot,\top$), but I doubt that anything interesting will come out here.

Comment: How do you arrive at $$\{x\} \subseteq X$$ I would think that a map of 0-presheaves is not inclusion but equality again?

Comment: I arrive at this by using the definitions.

Comment: I am very sorry. I still don't understand. I believe that the structure of a 0-category on 0-functors between two 0-categories is equality. Is that not so?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and taking the time and effort for my question!

I am still confused. What are the morphisms of $\{0,1\}$? 

If it is only the identities, then a natural transformation $X' \rightarrow Y'$ would associate to each object $c \in C$ an equality $X'(c) = Y'(c)$, which is the same as saying that $X' = Y'$ as functions, no?

Comment: You are right that the initial version of my question was not correct. I have revised it completely. Now it should be correct. Please check  again.

Comment: A set $X$ is a category enriched, not over the discrete monoidal category $\{0,1\}$, but over the monoidal category $\{0<1\}$ where tensor product is infimum. Here composition of morphisms in $X$ is the transitivity of equality. Sadly, then, this category $\{0<1\}$ over which $0$-cats are enriched is not a $0$-cat itself, but a $(0,1)$-cat instead.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Yes. Have you read my full answer? All what you say is contained in it.

Comment: @downvoter: How can I improve my answer?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sure. I just wanted to emphasize my sadness :(

Answer (score 3):

***For $n=0$ this says:***

If $C$ is a set, for any two elements there is a $(-1)$-category of morphism,(two elements are either equal or not , which corresponds to true, false respectively.) And the corresponding $0-$$\mathrm{Hom}$ is given by Kronecker Delta
$$\mathrm{Hom}(c, d) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } c = d \\
    0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
The Yoneda Embedding is a set-theoretic function which sends an element to its indicator function. The *set* of $0$-presheaves is the functions of $X$ to $\{0,1\}$, which can be identified with the power-set $P(X)$ of $X$. In this picture, the Yoneda-Embedding sends an element $c \in C$ to the singleton-set ${c}$, and a presheaf is nothing but a subset $X\subseteq C$.

Now Yoneda's Lemma should give a condition for when $X$ is equal to the singleton ${c}$, I think. What is it? What is the above isomorphism? What is a (-1)-functor?

Comment: Why are you putting your question as a self-answer? Just put this in the question post above if you have questions.

Comment: I wanted to show how far I got for 0, which is not a full solution. :-) Is this not the way to do it? My question regards the full case n=0,-1,-2